# NPM error. Eacess : permission denied, stat

Tags: npm

When executing `npm start` and I hit a compiling error, shortly after I receive this.

```
Module not found: Can't resolve '.../services/api' in '/mnt/c/Users/chung/dev/flatiron/labs/mod-5/herschmersch/frontend-herschmersch/src/containers'
/mnt/c/Users/chung/dev/flatiron/labs/mod-5/herschmersch/frontend-herschmersch/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js:19
  throw err;
  ^

[Error: EACCES: permission denied, stat '/mnt/c/Documents and Settings'] {
  errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'stat',
  path: '/mnt/c/Documents and Settings'
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! frontend-herschmersch@0.1.0 start: `PORT=3001 react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the frontend-herschmersch@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/nathan/.npm/_logs/2020-10-09T04_07_10_726Z-debug.log
```

When I remove what was originally causing the error in my react code, it seems to work. I've also had a similar issue when trying to install plotly.

Any advice would be great!

Thank you

#### EDIT

I also notice that this is going on in my node_modules folder:

```
// ♥  ls -la /usr/local/lib/node_modules
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 1 nathan nathan 512 Oct  8 23:37 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root   root   512 Oct  7 12:04 ..
```

I tried to change the owner but there's another line that says root.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  What operating system are you using?

Comment: Thank you. :) I'm using windows 10 with WSL/Ubuntu!